# huge size of /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main/base/1 directory (postgresql)

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, postgresql-9.3

i'm using postgresql 9.3.4 and real size of database is about 5.5 GB but POSTGRESQL fill disk about 256 GB !!

is this POSTGRESQL Cache and what is method to clean thing issue ?

Comment: PostgreSQL has no cache. So no, it isn't. How do you determine that "real size of database is 5.5 GB"? At a guess, you've turned autovacuum off and have a massively bloated database. See: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Show_database_bloat . To work out table sizes, see: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Disk_Usage . Please edit the question with information based on this comment then comment here when done.

Comment: i have same database in MYSQL too. so phpmyadmin showing size of all data is about 5.5 GB

Comment: after "ps -axww | grep autovacuum" .. autovacuum seems up and running

Comment: OK, so go read those links. Check for bloat, and run the disk usage query. Then report the results by editing your question and commenting here when done. 256GB vs 5.5GB is a bit too much to just be normal data type storage differences, index sizes, etc, so something isn't right, but I need that information to help you.